# jest jquery call returning nothing after DOM setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jestjs

I am following this quide on jest and jquery testing -> https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery

I have setup a real simple test:

```
test('displays a user after a click', () => {
    const $ = require('jquery');

    // Set up our document body
    document.body.innerHTML =
        '<div>' +
        '  <span id="username" />' +
        '  <button id="button" />' +
        '</div>';
    console.log($('#username'));
    console.log(document.body.outerHTML)
});
```

and my output:

```
 console.log apps/quoting/tests/unit/test_static/example.test.js:11
    jQuery { '0': HTMLSpanElement {}, length: 1 }

  console.log apps/quoting/tests/unit/test_static/example.test.js:12
    <body><div>  <span id="username">  <button id="button"></button></span></div></body>
```

but this does not look like the same response I would get from a normal jquery call inside a browser eg:

```
$('#1589952632187')
Object { 0: div#1589952632187.card.m-3.selected_product, length: 1 }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am quite stuck on this.

Some additional info:

```
node --version
v12.16.3
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "x"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {},
  "browserify-shim": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    },
    "select2": {
      "exports": null,
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    },
    "jquery-ui-bundle": {
      "exports": null,
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "browserify": "^16.5.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.14",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui-bundle": "^1.12.1-migrate",
    "mustache": "^4.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "select2": "^4.0.13",
    "select2-bootstrap-theme": "0.1.0-beta.10",
    "tinyify": "^2.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem? The thing you posted doesn't return 'nothing', it's definitely 'something'. What exactly are your expectations?

Comment: yeah I realized last night looking over the code and creating a new test case that "something" is returned I just didn't know at the time what I was looking at as firefox debugger represents the object a bit differently I guess. Thanks for your feedback